# How to return list of attribute values from a list of objects

Tags: python, list, attributes

I have a list of objects with the same attribute, I want a list consisting of only of that attribute, what's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
map(lambda obj: obj.YOUR_ATTRIBUTE, [obj1, obj2, obj3 ...])
```